# Create Facebook app to run in side margin of fan page

Tags: facebook

I know how to create an application that can be installed as a tab on a Facebook fan page, but what can I do to get more exposure on the main page.

For example, I would like to install an app that was permanently open in the left hand column of a fan page.

Is this possible?  What is this called?  How do I get started?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible. It's called the **narrow profile box**.

1. Go to the Developer application
2. View My Applications
3. Edit the settings
4. Click "Profiles"
5. Make sure you have "Narrow" selected

[image]

This will let your users install the application into the left hand column of their profile or fan page.

Facebook [claims that they will disable this functionality](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Roadmap_Profile) "at some point", but they are notoriously bad at following through on such promises.